# Rack::Lock does not appear as a middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, thread-safety, middleware

I have been read about threadsafe and multithread concepts on Rails, so I knew the middleware `Rack::Lock` and the command `rake middleware`. But when I tried to run it in my app, this middleware does not appear in the list.

What does this mean? Why does `Rack::Lock` not appear? How does Rails manage to be threadsafe if this middleware doesn't appear?.

The command output of `rake middleware`:

```
use Rack::Sendfile
use ActionDispatch::Static
use ActionDispatch::Executor
use Rack::Runtime
use Rack::MethodOverride
use ActionDispatch::RequestId
use Rails::Rack::Logger
use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
use WebConsole::Middleware
use ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
use ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
use ActionDispatch::Reloader
use ActionDispatch::Callbacks
use ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending
use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
use ActionDispatch::Flash
use Rack::Head
use Rack::ConditionalGet
use Rack::ETag
use Warden::Manager
use OmniAuth::Strategies::Twitter
use OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook
run Myapp::Application.routes
```

I am using:

Rails 5.1 and Ruby 2.3.1

**Update:**

I have found on Rails 5 actually `Rack::Lock` is not present, so, how does Rails 5 manage `threadsafe`?

Comment: `Rack::Lock`(not `Rake::Lock`) is disabled in development because it enables class caching.

Comment: Corrected, and I run `RAILS_ENV=production rake middleware` in the prduction server and the output is the same.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/17102

Comment: It seems that `Rack::Lock` has not been removed from Rails.